# Cosmic microwave background the same as the first visible light at 379,000 yrs after the Big Bang? How do these measure the age of the universe?

Tags: astrophysics, cosmology, cosmic-microwave-background, age

Was the CMB emitted at the same time as visible light at 379,000 yrs after the BB ? Was this a one time event ? If headed away from us, how does it measure the age of the universe?

Comment: What does "the same as" mean in your question? I ask because of course microwaves and visible light are not the same frequency, but I cannot guess what other "same"ness you are asking about.

Comment: The CMB is blackbody radiation. It was visible when it was originally released, but it's now redshifted to the microwave band because of expansion. Its original color was approximately  $$\Large{\color{#ffb46b}■}$$

Comment: *"If headed away from us"* What do you mean? You can't see light that's heading away from you. The CMB was released everywhere (over a relatively short time span), heading in every direction.